# PHP echo giving the wrong output

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use the PHP function thingy echo, it sends out something weird.
When I write:

```
<?php
echo'<p>Hello</p>'
?>
```

And what I get out is:

```
Hello

') ?> 
^^ This thing, I don't know why but it's there
```

I can remove those parts from the code and they disappears but it kind of ruins the code..

Comment: Ensure that your webserver is executing the PHP, and not simply sending the script itself to the browser

Comment: Start with learning basic PHP

Comment: PHP isn't installed or your file doesn't have `.php` extension.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put ';' at the end of line like this : `<?php echo'<p>Hello</p>'; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

**You forgot this:** ***`;`***

So please insert it at the end of `echo smth`:

```
<?php
echo'<p>Hello</p>'; 
//     here it is ^
?>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, not use to PHP, and just copied from a tutorial so was really weirded out why It was giving me an error...

Answer (score 1):

Put `;` at the end

```
<?php
echo'<p>Hello</p>';
?>
```